# typing is not possible in text field in safari

Tags: input, safari, field

in this page: https://www.pentaferte.com/en/request-information-about-our-products/
it occurs the following problem: 
in the "product" field, if you click on "Other" you are not able to type anything in the field.

How can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just adding form tag!